# AngularJS $scope includes my bound variable but remains inaccessible later on, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just starting to learn AngularJS and find it fascinating, however it is also acting somewhat strangely (IMO). I was going through some examples on the Angular site and decided to try to add a repeat input that would be passed into the factory for use. I have the following code:

```js
// script.js

var myApp = angular.module('myServiceModule', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'notify', function($scope, notify) {
    var repeat = Number($scope.repeat);
    console.log($scope);        // <-- inspecting $scope object shows the $scope.repeat value as a string "3"
    console.log($scope.repeat); // <-- reports undefined!?
    $scope.callNotify = function(msg, repeat) {
      notify(msg, repeat);
    };
  }]
);

myApp.factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
  var msgs = [];
  return function(msg, repeat) { // <-- trying to pass repeat here
    msgs.push(msg);
    if (msgs.length == repeat) { // <-- for use here
      win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
      msgs = [];
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!-- index.html //-->

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Services test 1 (Factory method)</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myServiceModule">
    <div id='simple' ng-controller="MyController">
      <p>Let's try a simple notification service!</p>
      <input ng-init="repeat='3'" ng-model="repeat">
      <input ng-init="message='test'" ng-model="message">
      <button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
      <p>Click {{repeat}} times to see an alert</p>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I am wondering why, when I console.log($scope), I can see the $scope.repeat is there and is "3" as expected. Yet, on the line right below where I inspect the $scope by itself, I console.log($scope.repeat) and find it is returning "undefined". What (all) am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your input!

Edit: original code for this can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller will run in this order

1. console.log($scope);
2. console.log($scope.repeat);
3. ng-init="repeat='3'"

So in fact when you ran

```
console.log($scope);
```

It actually didn't have init but because you ng-init="repeat='3'" ran half a millisecond later and you inspected the $scope variable 2 seconds after it ran, it was added on.  As an experiment try in your console

```
var test = {hello: 1, testing: 2, tests: 3, more: function(){ return 'hello' }}
console.log(test)
test.addthis = 'Did I add this?'
```

You will see when you inspect your console.log it shows the thing you added after.  This is because objects are by reference so if you console.log the object it won't be a snapshot of how it was at the time but rather what it is no matter how it changes.

**EDIT**
After that try

```
var test = {hello: 1, testing: 2, tests: 3, more: function(){ return 'hello' }}
console.log(test)
console.log("will it work? : " + test.addthis)
test.addthis = 'Did I add this?'
```

Make sense?

So in fact what you saw in your console was a later time when the ng-init happened. And thats why when you tried to log console.log($scope.repeat); it gave you an undefined since this will log the value at the point of time.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know.

Comment: The repeat data is still not getting through to my call to callNotify though. Very odd stuff.

Comment: It should work, maybe you have another error somewhere else . Have you updated your html from button ng-click="callNotify(message);"  to button ng-click="callNotify(message, repeat);"

Comment: It wasnt erroring per se (heuristic error perhaps), however passing in a variable "r" into the callNotify function after msg was failing. I found that I could simply access the $scope.repeat data within the function anyhow, so no worries there. It is odd that I was not able to add a new var to the function  though.

I added an answer just a few min ago that shows how I got it to work (with help from you and Levi of course). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `ng-init`. You  should init your variables in your controller.

Because, if the controller is executed first, you `ng-init` tags will be useless and unsync.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myServiceModule', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'notify', function($scope, notify) { 
    $scope.repeat = 3; 
    $scope.message = "test";

    console.log($scope);        // <-- inspecting $scope object shows the $scope.repeat value as a string "3"
    console.log($scope.repeat); // <-- reports undefined!?
    $scope.callNotify = function(msg, repeat) {
      notify(msg, repeat);
    };
  }]
);
```

Then in your index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Services test 1 (Factory method)</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myServiceModule">
    <div id='simple' ng-controller="MyController">
      <p>Let's try a simple notification service!</p>
      <input ng-model="repeat">
      <input ng-model="message">
      <button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
      <p>Click {{repeat}} times to see an alert</p>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that does solve the availability issue. Thanks! I'm still working on getting the repeat data into the factory to determine if the message can be output in the win.alert()

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some assistance from Levi and Yang Li (Thanks!) This was found to work:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myServiceModule', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'notify', function($scope, notify) {
    $scope.repeat = 3;
    $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
      notify(msg, $scope.repeat);
    };
  }]
);

myApp.factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
  var msgs = [];
  return function(msg, repeat) {
    msgs.push(msg);
    if (msgs.length == repeat) {
      win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
      msgs = [];
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Services test 1 (Factory method)</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myServiceModule">
    <div id='simple' ng-controller="MyController">
      <p>Let's try a simple notification service!</p>
      <input ng-model="repeat" type="number">
      <input ng-init="message='test'" ng-model="message">
      <button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
      <p>Click {{repeat}} times to see an alert</p>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically, I just wanted to see if I could manually control how many clicks would be required to fire the win.alert()